# Python 2.7 : Removal of accents from an <str> - Still won't work

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I am receiving str datas trough a websocket connection, and trying to remove accents (as well as lowering the text / turning ' ' into '-' ..)

And I, even with the hundreds of questions having being asked and answered here, still fail at it.

here's the part of the code trying to do this, parsed[4][7:] being my text to translate

```
    if parsed[4][:6]=="!strat":
        shiftedtxt=''
        txt=parsed[4][7:].lower().decode('unicode-escape')
        hope=''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', txt) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
        for i in hope:
            if i==' ':
                shiftedtxt+='-'
            else:
                shiftedtxt+=i
        ws.send(room+"|http://pokestrat.com/fiche_pokemon/"+shiftedtxt+".php")
```

I'm typically trying to translate 'Ténéfix' into 'tenefix'.

As suggested by the answers on this site, i'm using the

```
''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', txt) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
```

method.

When trying step by step :

```
'éô'.decode('unicode-escape')
```

yields

```
u'\xe9\xf4'
```

and

```
>>> s=u'\xe9\xf4'
>>> ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if     unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
```

yields

```
u'eo'
```

Thus, things should .. work ? Yet they don't.
For exemple, 'ténéfix' returns 'tA©nA©fix', which i cannot explain.
Why ?

Edit : here's the full code : http://pastebin.com/aJ1Rk1pV

Comment: the issue is probably around `parsed[4][7:].lower().decode('unicode-escape')`

Comment: @njzk2 parsed[4] is a string object physically being a message on a chat room.
parsed[:6] is checked to be !strat, if verified, then parsed [7:] should be a word.
It is designed so that user ask "!strat Ténéfix". Maybe strings coming from websockets aren't strings ?..

Comment: didn't you check the actual content of the value that causes the issue ?

Comment: I can't put debug prints in the code. For an unknown reason, using a websocket connection appear to be making any print order ineffective. After starting this program, I can simply ask for "print 1" in the console, and he won't print anything ._. This is why i'm trying step to step tests, which appear to work ... and thus trouble me even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt=parsed[4][7:].lower().decode('unicode-escape')
```

Are you sure you want to parse part of the submitted text as a Python unicode string literal? This seems unlikely. `!strat Ténéfix` does not contain any Python string escapes (like `\uNNNN`, `\n` etc).

Judging by `tA©nA©fix` you are receiving UTF-8-encoded bytes but you're decoding them as ISO-8859-1, which is the passthrough encoding for `unicode-escape`. Instead, try:

```
txt=parsed[4][7:].decode('utf-8').lower()
```

Lowercasing needs to happen after you have turned the byte sequence into Unicode text.

> When trying step by step: `'éô'.decode('unicode-escape')` yields `u'\xe9\xf4'`

For this to be true your terminal must be sending the characters `éô` as ISO-8859-1 (or the similar Windows code page 1252). That's a different encoding to UTF-8 which is what the websocket gives you, so the results are different.